# VB.NET list SQL Server names in combobox doesn't work in Windows 8 and 10

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

After testing my VB.NET application on Windows 7, everything works fine. I also tried it on different PC's that are running Windows 7 and everything works fine.

Until I tried it on Windows 8 and Windows 10. My VB.NET application has a combobox that fills all the SQL Server names that are found on the network on its login page, using with the For each row dt.rows command.

On Windows 8 and 10 when I try to open the combobox to see the SQL Server names, it is empty. Any suggestions or ideas?

The Code is the following :

```
Dim dt as datatable = sqldatasourceenumerator.instance.getdatasources 

For Each dr as datarow in dt.rows

combobox.items.add(String.concat(dr("servername")

Next
```

Comment: put more light on the issue like error shown code etc

Comment: There isnt any error shown it just doesnt fill the combobox with the sql server names . Combobox is empty

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show us some code?

Comment: Is the code to fill the combobox being hit? Do you have a try catch wrapped around a method that is consuming an error instead of reporting it? Do you need to grant different network control/permission/access on Win8/10 to allow the OS to find servers on the network in this manner?

Comment: No there isnt any different network control  / access. The code is the following Dim dt as datatable = sqldatasourceenumerator.instance.getdatasources

Comment: put the details in the question, not in the comments. code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: although missing information.. perhaps it was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977719/get-sql-server-instances-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the service is running. After Windows upgrade, SQL Server Service do not automatically start at system reboot.